# Set Cell Value on Clicking Other Cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to perform the simple task of having a cell A's value change depending on whether the user clicked cell B, C, or D. For some reason, the code below only works for the first with statement (in chis case, the one that would set cell A's value to "Low"). Does anyone know why it doesnt work when I click B or C? Any help with this code would be great! Thank you!

```
Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

With Target

If Not Intersect(.Cells, Columns(1)) Is Nothing Or .Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & ActiveCell.row).Value = "Low"

If Not Intersect(.Cells, Columns(2)) Is Nothing Or .Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & ActiveCell.row).Value = "Medium"

If Not Intersect(.Cells, Columns(3)) Is Nothing Or .Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & ActiveCell.row).Value = "High"

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: To be clear, do you want a click in `B` to result in "Low" in `A`?  And `C` results in "Medium", and `D` results in "High"?

Comment: Yep, thats all I need. If I click B, then A says Low. If I click C, then A is Medium, and if I click C, then A says High

Comment: Any ideas on how to fix?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

your first statement will cause the routine to exit if it isn't the first column. Change the tests around, and you will have a little more success

Also, as you are looking for specific columns, check them with a select case statement to make it less crowded

```
Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

With Target

    if .Count > 1 then exit sub
    Select Case .column
        Case 2
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & ActiveCell.row).Value = "Low"
        Case 3
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & ActiveCell.row).Value = "Medium"
        Case 4
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & ActiveCell.row).Value = "High"
    end Select
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rOut As Range

With Target
   Set rOut = Me.Range("A" & .Row)
   If .Count = 1 Then
       If Not Intersect(.Cells, Columns(2)) Is Nothing Then
            rOut.Value = "Low"
       Else
            If Not Intersect(.Cells, Columns(3)) Is Nothing Then
                rOut.Value = "Medium"
            Else
                If Not Intersect(.Cells, Columns(4)) Is Nothing Then
                    rOut.Value = "High"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End With

End Sub
```